# How can i undo sharpening operation on image using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

There are multiple ways to do sharpening on image using matlab
for example
    im=imsharpen(old_image,'Radius',2,'Amount',1);
    im=imfilter(old_image,fspecial('unsharp'));
    imshow(im)
how can i  undo this operation(sharpening) and return the original image??

Comment: Better keep the original somewhere as it's highly questionable if these approaches can be inverted perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot undo the effect of a filter, in general. Filtering, even sharpening filters, combines the values in a neighborhood, reducing information.

For a small class of **linear** filters, those that do not zero out any frequencies, it is possible to reverse the operation to a certain extent. This requires that no clipping occurred. That is, the result of the filter was saved as floating-point values rather than uint8 or similar. Reversing the operation then involves multiplying in the frequency domain by the point-wise inverse of the filter. The linear filter kernel *h* convolves the image *f*, that implies that they are multiplied in the frequency domain, roughly: `g = ifftn(fftn(f).*fftn(h))`. Then `f = ifftn(fftn(g)./fftn(h))`.

I say roughly because the above requires padding `h` to the size of `f`.

Note that where `fftn(h)` is 0, the division results in NaN (since you do 0/0), not the original value of *f*. This puts a strong limit to the class of filters that you can "undo". Furthermore, if the filtered image has noise added (this is likely except for purely theoretical cases) then the noise will be amplified for frequencies where the filter has small values. Basically, even small amounts of noise make this process fail.

The [Wiener filter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter) does the above with regularización, such that noise and near-zero filter values don't cause to blow out your answer. There are more complex iterative solvers for the ill-posed inverse transform, but that is a large topic. Start your search with Wiener and you'll eventually discover those too.

On the other hand, if you are looking for a filter that does the opposite --smoothing -- look for example for `imgaussfilt`.